# Using the max_network_delay option of the Corosync

Tags: networking, pacemaker, corosync

I have the cluster based on pacemaker and corosync. Cluster nodes are located in several data centers. And there is up to 450 ms ping latency between some of the nodes. Sometimes these delays lead to split brains.

I have found the `max_network_delay` option for the corosync.

Documentation says:

> [HeartBeating mechanism] This constant specifies in milliseconds the approximate delay that your network takes to transport one packet from one machine to another. This value is to be set by system engineers and please don't change if not sure as this affects the failure detection mechanism using heartbeat. (default: 50ms)

Also, there is the warning:

> It is not recommended to override this value without guidance from the corosync community.

But I haven't found any information about using this option.

Can anyone help me? Should I use this option or maybe there are some other options which can help me?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use this option or maybe there are some other options which can help me?

As the question is tagged with Pacemaker, I am going to assume you're using Corosync for Pacemaker communication. If this is the case, I would suggest using the booth plugin for Pacemaker. Managing service failover across geographically separate pacemaker cluster is booth's primary purpose.
https://github.com/ClusterLabs/booth

This would be quite a design change as you would no longer have one cluster, but a cluster for each different location. Single node clusters will work, but aren't advised (you cannot trust a node to fence itself).

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer by the mail from the corosync/pacemaker community:

> And there is up to 450 ms ping latency between some of the nodes. Sometimes these delays lead to split brains.

Yep, that's quite a lot. Enlarge token timeout so something like:

```
totem {
...
        token: 5000
...
}
```

will help

> I have found the max_network_delay option for the corosync.

This option does nothing until **heartbeat_failures_allowed** is set. I 
don't know if you have it enabled, but I would recommend to not enable it.

Regards,
   Honza